# Why LazyColumn does not recompose when data updets JetPack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata, lazylist

Why LazyColumn does not recompose when data updets? data really updates I see it in log:

```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(5.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

    val returnItemsList by viewModel.data.observeAsState(emptyList())
    val returnLiveData by viewModel.returnLiveData.observeAsState()
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                for (i in returnItemsList) Log.d(TAG, "returnItemsList ${i.amount}        ${i.returnType} ")
            },
            text = returnLiveData?.clientName ?: "",
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.gray_600),
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.spinner_main).value.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(paddingValues)
        ) {
            items(items = returnItemsList, key = { item -> item.returnItemId }) { item ->
                ReturnContentItem(item) {
                    inputViewModel.setItem(it)
                    viewModel.openInputDialog(it)
                }
            }
        }
```

ViewModel:
var data: MutableLiveData<List> = MutableLiveData()
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

data.postValue(db.productDao().getReturnProduct(SimpleSQLiteQuery(query)))
}`

Try to change var to val , use remember in fragment

Comment: Please edit your post and also include how you pass `returnItemsList` to the Composable.

Comment: There are a lot of compile errors in your code, please fix them. Also, we need to see the entire compose function including its parameters. We also need to know how you retrieve the LiveData from the view model and pass it to the composable.